# Python Requests GET returns 200 but POST returns 404

Tags: post, python-requests

I'm trying to log in to a site (www.scribd.com) using python's request library.
The login page is https://www.scribd.com/login.
When I do the following, everything works great and I get a status code of 200, so I know that the page exists:

```
import requests
BASE_URL = "https://www.scribd.com/"
LOGIN_URL = BASE_URL + "login"
r=requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.reason)
```

However, if I make a POST request (whether I include my login details or not, headers or not, etc.), I consistently get a 404 response. I have tried this same pattern with other websites, and I will get a 200 OK status code for other websites for both POST and GET.
ie,:

```
BASE_URL_IG='https://www.instagram.com/'
LOGIN_URL_IG=BASE_URL_IG+'accounts/login'

r = requests.get(LOGIN_URL_IG)
print(r.reason)
print(r.status_code)

r = requests.post(LOGIN_URL_IG)
print(r.reason)
print(r.status_code)
```

I'm not sure what else to try, but I can't seem to replicate this issue on any other sites. I've also tried in Postman but get the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its okay for backends to open up a route for GET but not for POST. So that should not be surprising. For example, you may allow the users to GET a list of items on a shopping website but you will allow only verified and authorised users to POST a new item.

Here is how you can copy a request as CURL using your browser.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/replay-a-network-request-in-curl

I got a 200 response when I copied the CURL command for the login request using the method above. However, its encoding was messed up. The important point is that, the API does return 200 response. You just need to fine tune the parameters. Good luck :)